# Swift custom tableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have created a custom `UITableViewCell` with a label on the far left (respects the parent margins) and it displays correctly. However, when I set an image using `imageView.image` (from the `UITableViewCell`), the label does not move to the right and so the label and the image are on top of each other. Any ideas how to make the label behave like the default label where it will move to the right to make way for the image?

[image: image overlap with label]

Comment: You need to update the label's frame (or auto-layout constraints) when an image is present.

Comment: do you have a code example on how to do that?

Comment: If you're setting frames, `label.frame = CGRect(…)`

Comment: I was hoping that there is some way that it will automagically move instead of me having to move the label when I also set the image in the imageView

Comment: You could create a constraint connecting the left side of the label to the right side of the image view

Comment: You can write   self.lblTrailing.constant = 50 in your custom cell.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to "automagically" move the label. You have to update the label's constrain when displaying the image.

Comment: This is because of you are set image to default(Apple build in) imageView in your tableview cell. Create your own custom cell with custom UIImaView so that you can easy to set auto layout to that UIImageView view and label.

Comment: Thanks sticker. Looks like I will have to implement my own image view in the custom cell and not use the uitableviewcell version. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the cell from storyboard make sure you have set the `UITableViewCell` style to `Custom`.

**Edit:**

I saw your comment above.
If you don't wish to create a custom `UITableViewCell` class, you can still use default `UITableViewCell` with style set to `Basic`

So you can obtain its properties:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Your text";
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Your image name"];
    UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
    cell.accessoryView = mySwitch;

    // Define the state of the switch because the cell will get recycled as you scroll.
    BOOL isOn;
    [mySwitch setOn:isOn];

    return cell;
}
```

The other solution is mentioned as commented above: You have to subclass `UITableViewCell`, drag and drop 3 `IBOutlet`s and reference them in `.h` file.

Comment: I had already done that but wanted to reuse the imageView of the uitableviewcell. But looks like that does not work.